# How can i retry value in dynamic xpath with selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

I have tried to retrive the value found here:

[image: 42,959]

with little success, since the xpath modifies itself dynamically and there is no pattern to it. I have tried the following variants

```
String folioValue=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"2027855965\"]/tbody[2]/tr/td[8]")).getText();
```

and

```
 String folioValue=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.total")).getText();
```

Any ideas on what I could use for this task? Thank you.

Comment: Update the question with some of the outer HTML in text format.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with following `css selector`.

```
String folioValue=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("td.total")).getText();
```

Comment: hello, thanks for the input. I have manage to retrieve a value but unfortunattely it is from a different column. the element found is looks like this ,<td align="right>173</td>. Do you know how i can differentiate between the 2 elements?

Comment: You need to post HTML both the element and mentioned which one you want to ignore